# TensorFlow 2 - does NumPy numerical values and arrays cause new graphs for TF Function?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0

Does "**numerical Python values**" stated in the [Hands on ML 2](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/) include NumPy int, float, and array? Do we need to explicitly create a TF Tensor or a TF DataSet from a NumPy construct as the argument of a TF Function?

[Hands on ML 2](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/) Chapter 12 Auto Graph and Tracing:

> By default, a TF Function generates a new graph for every unique set
> of intput shapes and data types and caches it for subsequent calls.
> ... However ***this is only true for tensor arguments***: if you pass
> numerical Python values to a TF Function, a new graph will be
> generated for every distinct value. ...
>
> if you pass **numerical Python values** to a TF function, a new graph will
> be generated for every distinct values. If you call a TF function many
> times with different numerical Python values, then many graphs will be
> generated, slowing down your program and using up a lot of RAM (you
> must delete the TF Function to release it).
>
> Python values should be reserved for arguments that will have few
> unique values, such as hyper parameters like the number of neurons per
> layer. This allows TensorFlow to better optimize each variant fo yor
> model.

The 3rd rule stated in the TensorFlow document [Rules of tracing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#rules_of_tracing) corresponds with Python int, float, boolean, str , etc that will cause a new graph part. But not sure if the 5th rule (all other Python types) applies to NumPy constructs.

> A Function determines whether to reuse a traced ConcreteFunction by computing a cache key from an input's args and kwargs.  A cache key is a key that identifies a ConcreteFunction based on the
> input args and kwargs of the Function call, according to the following
> rules (which may change):
>
> 1. The key generated for a tf.Tensor is its shape and dtype.
> 2. The key generated for a tf.Variable is a unique variable id.
> 3. The key generated for a Python primitive (like int, float, str) is its value.
> 4. The key generated for nested dicts, lists, tuples, namedtuples, and attrs is the flattened tuple of leaf-keys (see nest.flatten). (As a
>    result of this flattening, calling a concrete function with a
>    different nesting structure than the one used during tracing will
>    result in a TypeError).
> 5. For all other Python types the key is unique to the object. This way a
>    function or method is traced independently for each instance it is
>    called with.

I suppose the fact [tf.numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) exists suggests that the TF Function tracing will generate a new graph, but need a definite confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think changing the values inside numpy arrays will generate a new graph. Consider the following minimal code exampls:

```
@tf.function 
def test(input): 
  print("Tracing with input= ", input)
  tf.print("Executing with input = ", input)
```

The first print is only executed during tracing, the second for every call. Calling it with a list leads to:

```
test([1,2])
test([3,4])
>>> Tracing with input =  [1, 2]
>>> Executing with input [1, 2]
>>> Tracing with input =  [3, 4]
>>> Executing with input [3, 4]
```

whereas calling it with numpy-arrays leads to:

```
test(np.array([1,2]))
test(np.array([3,4]))
>>> Tracing with input =  Tensor("input:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
>>> Executing with input [1 2]
>>> Executing with input [3, 4]
```

Here no tracing is done for the second call. This suggests at least that numpy-arrays are handled the same way as tensorflow tensors.